# coroutines and Django clickjacking middleware

Tags: django, django-views, aiohttp, django-middleware

I am trying to use the [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library with Django. I have followed the tutorial but get the following error defining one of my `view` methods as `async`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 97, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/Users/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The minimal working example I have of this is as follows:

```
async def conversion_form_process(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ConversionForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    else:
        form = ConversionForm()

    return render(request, 'mainpage.html', {'form': form})
```

This suggests that it has to do with the `async` keyword but I don't know how to fix it. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, *aiohttp* is not compatible with *Django*.

It uses completely different paradigm.